# Matlab error-"Input must be a cell array of strings"...how to get unique values from numeric cell..iff..matrix is of mixed values

Tags: matlab

Here is my code:

```
A={2,'small','low','unacc';2,'small','med','unacc';2,'small','high','unacc';4,'big','low','unacc';4,'big','high','acc';'more','big','med','acc';'more','big','high','vgood';4,'med','med','acc'};
```

I want to get all unique values from the first column of above matrix

`uniques(A(:,1))` is giving error

Comment: `A(:,1)` is not a cell array of strings. You have doubles in it as well.

Comment: so how to get the unique from this.any other solution?

Comment: just put ' before and after the 2 (or any other number), then it's treated as a string as well.

Answer (score 1):

As @excaza said, you first need to change the double values  string

```
A={2,'small','low','unacc';2,'small','med','unacc';...
   2,'small','high','unacc';4,'big','low','unacc';...
   4,'big','high','acc'; 'more','big','med','acc';...
   'more','big','high','vgood';4,'med','med','acc'};

A_full_string = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x), A, 'UniformOutput',0);
```

Basicly, [`num2str`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) takes a number or a string as an input and returns this value as a string.
[`cellfun`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) applies a function to every element of a cell array.

Now all your values are string values :

```
unique(A_full_string(:,1))

ans = 

    '2'
    '4'
    'more'
```